# reading file line by line and adding lines to array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to read a file line by line in Java. Each line is added as an item to an array. Problem is that, I have to create the array based on the number of lines in the file while I am reading line by line.

I can use two separate `while` loops one for counting and then creating the array and then adding items. But it is not efficient for large files.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(convertedFile))) {
  String line = "";
  int maxRows = 0;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] str = line.split(" ");
    maxColumns = str.length;
    theRows[ maxRows ] = new OneRow( maxColumns );   // ERROR
    theRows[ maxRows ].add( str );
    ++maxRows;
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Consider `private OneRow [] theRows;` and `OneRow` is defined as `String []`. the file looks like

```
Item1    Item2   Item3   ...
2,3       4n     2.2n
3,21      AF     AF
...
```

Comment: You could use an ArrayList.

Comment: Also: "readAllLines" : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). ArrayList is resisable array.And is equivalent to C++ Vector.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(convertedFile))) 
{ 
    List<String> str= new ArrayList<>();
    String line = ""; 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    str.add(line.split(" "));
    } 
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e){ 
 System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: @mahmood That's because it's an `List<String>` not a `List<String[]>`. Anyway, *do not use the second one*. If you want a 2D array, use `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Why you need to make ArrayList of arrays ?

Comment: So, your `str` is actually my `theRows`. Right?

Comment: My str is like your array str

Comment: Is there a tabulation between this two items or only one space?

Comment: They are not tabs. just one space. I formatted here to be more meaningful

Comment: One more question. How can I access the elements then? According to your code, `str.get(0)` will return `{Item1} {Item2} {Item3}`. How to iterate over each element of `str`?

Comment: Make for loop with number of items.`str.get(i);`

Answer (score 5):

You can't resize an array. Use the `ArrayList` class instead:

```
private ArrayList<OneRow> theRows;

...

theRows.add(new OneRow(maxColumns));
```

Comment: What does it add to `theRows`? I want to add `str`

Comment: I want to add `String []` to `theRows`. Do you mean `private ArrayList<OneRow []> theRows;`?

Comment: without an initial assignment this will throw an NPE

Comment: @mahmood It adds `OneRow` objects, just like in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) data structure. If you are unfamiliar with how ArrayLists work I would read up on the documentation.